# Get custom field in user object

Tags: apex, lightning-experience

In my object manage runder User I have a custom field named Business Type, in my apex class I want to retreive the current logged in users Business Type. It can only be Commerical Or Residential. I do:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static user getBusinessType(){
    return [Select Business_Type__c From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
}
```

This succesfully runs but it doesnt say `Commercial` or `Residential` it returns:

```js
{
    id: "[somerandomnumer]"
}
```

How can make it so it gets the current user business type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once i checked on other test users this issue was fixed. Checking on system admin returned null which was what is was supposed to do.